# How can I get distinct values in COALESCE()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table values in this format

```
sam
jack
sam
john

Declare @name varchar(max)
select @name = COALESCE(@name + ', ','')+ user_email 
from   PostedCommentMaster where article_id = @id
```

How can I get distinct value

```
sam,jack,john
```

like this.

Comment: Why are you using `COALESCE` here? You first declare the @name variable, then immediately check to see whether it is null. It will always be null, as it will never get set to anything

Comment: @paul - This is one (undocumented) way to concatenate a column from a resultset.

Comment: I see, so `@name` is actually re-evaluated per row returned. clever.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can wrap the select statement into a subselect and apply coalesce on the results.

```
Declare @name varchar(max) 

select @name = COALESCE(@name + ', ','') + user_email 
from   (select distinct user_email 
        from   PostedCommentMaster 
        where article_id = @id) pc
```

Note that this uses an undocumented feature of SQL Server to concatenate the results into one string. While I can't find a link to it anymore, I recall reading that your should not rely on this behavior.

A better alternative would be to use the `FOR XML` syntax to return a concatenated string. [A search on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D%20stuff%20%22for%20xml%22%20concat&submit=search) returns multiple results you can use as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
Declare @name varchar(max) 
select 
    @name = COALESCE(@name + ', ','')+name from (select distinct user_email 
from 
    PostedCommentMaster) as t
where 
    article_id = @id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` for unique values.

```
Declare @name varchar(max)
select @name = COALESCE(@name + ', ','')+ user_email 
from   PostedCommentMaster where article_id = @id 
group by user_email
```

Answer (score 0):

Best You can use this one.

```
Declare @name varchar(max)
select @name = COALESCE(@name + ', ','')+ user_email  from (select distinct user_email 
from   PostedCommentMaster where article_id = @id ) as tblTemp
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct @name = COALESCE(@name + ', ','')+ user_email 
from   PostedCommentMaster where article_id = @id

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We prefer code answers to be accompanied with some explanation as to why the code solves the problem. Also, please consider using [code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on same issue. So my solution to this is-

1. Create a #temp table.
2. Insert distinct values to your #temp table.
3. Add your coalesce query.

   ```
   create table #emailList (user_email varchar(200))
   insert into #emailList select distinct user_email from   PostedCommentMaster 
   where article_id = @id

   Declare @name varchar(max)
   select @name = COALESCE(@name + ', ','')+ user_email 
   from   #emailList
   ```

   This is also helpful in fetching data from multiple tables using joins.